# Using nested CoroutineScopes to upload images and keeping track of them

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am a newbie to android coroutines my requirements

1. Need to upload 20 images
2. Keep track of upload(at least when it gets finished I need to hide progressBar of each image)
3. After uploading all the images need to enable a "next" button also
   Here is my try:

---

```
private fun startUploading(){
    // Get AWS data
    val accessKey = sharedPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.aws_access_key), "").toString()
    val secretKey = sharedPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.aws_secret_key), "").toString()
    val bucketName = sharedPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.aws_bucket_name), "").toString()
    val region = sharedPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.aws_region), "").toString()
    val distributionUrl = sharedPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.aws_distribution_url), "").toString()

    var totalImagesNeedToUpload = 0
    var totalImagesUploaded = 0
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        for (i in allCapturedImages.indices) {
            val allImageFiles = allCapturedImages[i].viewItem.ImageFiles
            totalImagesNeedToUpload += allImageFiles.size
            for (j in allImageFiles.indices) {
                CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                    while (true) {
                        val internetActive = utilsClassInstance.hasInternetConnected()
                        if (internetActive){
                            try {
                                val file = allImageFiles[j]
                                if (!file.uploaded) {
                                    // Upload the file
                                    val cfUrl = utilsClassInstance.uploadFile(file.imageFile, accessKey, secretKey, bucketName, region, distributionUrl)

                                    // Set the uploaded status to true
                                    file.uploaded = true
                                    file.uploadedUrl = cfUrl

                                    // Increment the count of total uploaded images
                                    totalImagesUploaded += 1

                                    // Upload is done for that particular set image
                                    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
                                        mainRecyclerAdapter?.uploadCompleteForViewItemImage(i, j, cfUrl)
                                        // Set the next button enabled
                                        if (totalImagesUploaded == totalImagesNeedToUpload){
                                            binding.btnNext.isEnabled = true
                                        }
                                    }
                                    break
                                }else{
                                    totalImagesUploaded += 1
                                    break
                                }
                            } catch (e: Exception) {
                                println(e.printStackTrace())
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
                        if (totalImagesUploaded == totalImagesNeedToUpload){
                            updateProgressForAllImages()
                            binding.btnNext.isEnabled = true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

    fun uploadFile(file: File, accessKey:String, secretKey:String, bucketName: String, region:String, distributionUrl: String): String{
    // Create a S3 client
    val s3Client = AmazonS3Client(BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey))
    s3Client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(region))

    // Create a put object
    val por = PutObjectRequest(bucketName, file.name, file)
    s3Client.putObject(por)

    // Override the response headers
    val override = ResponseHeaderOverrides()
    override.contentType = "image/jpeg"

    // Generate the url request
    val urlRequest = GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucketName, file.name)
    urlRequest.responseHeaders = override

    // Get the generated url
    val url = s3Client.generatePresignedUrl(urlRequest)
    return url.toString().replace("https://${bucketName}.s3.amazonaws.com/", distributionUrl)
}
```

1. There are total "n" images that I need to upload
2. every image is getting uploaded in different **Coroutine** because I need to do the parallel upload

The whole question is how to know that all the images are uploaded and enable a next button?

Comment: Please point out the problem you are facing. What outcome do you expect and what doesn't work? Does the code throw error or something else? Please ask a question.

Comment: SO is a _question_ and answer site. You posted your requirements and some code, but no _question_. See here and try again: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your code reminds me of a project I inherited with no handover .. both made me cry inside.

Comment: @RickyMo Please check again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems very unstructured. You have an infinite loop checking for network availability. You have a nested loop here to upload images (Why?). You are creating a lot of coroutine scopes and have no control over them

Based on the 3 requirements that you mentioned in the question, you can do something like this:

```kotlin
val imagesToUpload: List<File> = /* ... */
var filesUploaded = 0
lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted { 
    coroutineScope { // This will return only when all child coroutines have finished
        imagesToUpload.forEach { imageFile ->
            launch { // Run every upload in parallel
                val url = utilsClassInstance.uploadFile(file.imageFile, ...) // Assuming this is a non-blocking suspend function.
                filesUploaded++
                // Pass the `url` to your adapter to display the image
                binding.progressBar.progress = (filesUploaded * 100) / imagesToUpload.size // Update progress bar
            }
        }
    }
    // All images have been uploaded at this point.
    binding.btnNext.enabled = true
}
```

Ideally you should have used a `viewModelScope` and the upload code should be in a repository, but since you don't seem to have a proper architecture in place, I have used `lifecycleScope` which you can get inside an `Activity` or `Fragment`

Comment: `filesUploaded++` is being run in parallel coroutines on Dipatchers.IO. I don’t think that’s thread-safe. Since you’re assuming `uploadFile` suspends, you don’t need to specify IO, so you can let it run on Main and not worry about concurrently incrementing it.

Comment: Yeah I observed that. Can you suggest a simple solution for this? I don't want to add mutex locks in the answer and complicate it.

Comment: I edited my comment to suggest a solution as you were responding. Dispatchers.Main is single threaded so if you run the launched coroutines on Main it would be fine. I’m assuming `uploadFiles` suspends and doesn’t block. If it blocks you could wrap it in withContext.

Comment: Another point that should be made is that file uploads probably should be run on a coroutine scope that will outlive the Activity. Since this is in `launchWhenStarted` it will be canceled even if a dialog box pops up. But even with launch it would be canceled on a screen rotation. Even a ViewModel’s scope might be too short-lived for a file upload that you don’t want cancelled when you navigate away.

Comment: I guess viewModelScope might be okay here, as the user has to click on a Next button when all images get uploaded. So if he goes back in between, we can probably cancel the uploads. Depends on the use case. Btw what scope do you suggest?

Comment: @ArpitShukla i have added a upload file function also please do check it

Comment: I have added an infinite loop to check internet connectivity, unless there is a network connection I don't want to start upload i have also added break statements accordingly

Comment: The scope depends on the use case. ViewModel scope is appropriate if we want to cancel if the user backs out.

Comment: @SanketBhangale Your uploadFile function is not a suspend one. And neither have you a callback for upload completion. I haven't worked with AWS so am not aware of its API but I believe it provides you some callback for the upload completion. You first need to introduce that callback in your code. Then you can use [suspendCancellableCoroutine](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/suspend-cancellable-coroutine.html) to convert that callback based function to a suspend function.